# How do I move the last two characters of a column within the attribute table to another column?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, vbscript, address-parsing

I have data in a column that looks like the below example:

El Monte CA

I need to move the last 2 characters to a separate column. Which function in the field calculator will deliver those results?

Comment: I could guess that you are using ArcGIS since you tagged vbscript, but it would be helpful if you can confirm what software you are using. Also, if you are using ArcGIS, are you willing/able to use Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Right Function

```
Right( [textField], n )
(where n is the number of characters)
```

eg:
`Right(“abcdefg”, 3)` = “efg”

This is pretty handy for learning how to use the field calculator
http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0405/files/fieldcalc_1.pdf

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks please mark this answer as correct too, so it will help others.

Comment: Another option you may see is [textfield].split()[-1:]. Not better or worse, just different.@cl3 's answer is better than split() for a string with no spaces.

Comment: !textfield![-2:] using Python